# Iterate over multiple files, remove those who contains x specific characters

Tags: linux, shell

New to Shell. I have more than 10 thousand files and I have to delete files that contain the "<" characters less than 10 times.

`wc -l * 2>&1 | while read -r num file; do ((num < 10)) && echo rm "$file";` - this one removes files if they have less than 10 lines, but how do I put "<" character?

Comment: Can `<` appear multiple times in a single line?

Comment: No, it isn't possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With GNU `grep`, bash and GNU `xargs`:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

grep -cZ '<' * |
while IFS='' read -r -d '' file && read count
do
    (( count < 10 )) && printf '%s\0' "$file"
done |
xargs -0r rm
```

###### Explanations

`grep -cZ` outputs a stream of `file` `\0` `count` `\n` records.

You process it with a `while` loop that `read`s the `file` (using a `NUL`-byte delimiter) and the `count` (using a newline delimiter).

You do your filtering logic and output the files that you want to delete (in the form of `NUL`-delimited records).

Finally, `xargs -r0 rm` does the deletion of the files

---

Here's an alternative with GNU `awk` and `xargs`:

```bash
awk -v n=10 '
    FNR == 1 {
        count = 0
    }
    /</ && ++count >= n {
        nextfile
    }
    ENDFILE {
        if (count < n)
            printf "%s%c", FILENAME, 0
    }
' * |
xargs -0r rm
`
```

Answer (score 1):

Using GNU `grep` (for the `-m` option, to make it a bit more efficient):

```
#!/bin/bash

for f in *; do
    (( $(grep -Fc -m10 \< "$f") < 10 )) && echo rm "$f"
done
```

Drop the `echo` if output looks fine.